# Cancel a group of HTTP requests in twisted

Tags: python, http, twisted

I'm making several HTTP requests with twisted.web.client.getPage, and would like to be able to cancel some of them at the user's request. Ideally I would like to do something like:

```
# Pseudocode, getPage doesn't work like this:
getPage(url1, "group1")
getPage(url2, "group1")
getPage(url3, "group1")
...

# Later on
reactor.cancel_all("group1")
```

Maybe I could add all the Deferreds to a DeferredList, but I have a lot of small requests, so most of the requests would be finished at a given time anyway (plus, I don't know if you can add Deferreds to a existing DeferredList)... Is there a more idiomatic solution?

Answer (score 1):

You are describing two separate issues.  First, can an HTTP request made with `getPage` be cancelled at all?  No, it can't.  Second, can operations be grouped together so that they can all be cancelled simultaneously.  Sure, that doesn't involve anything very special:

```
def cancel(group):
    for job in group:
        job.cancel()

group = []
group.append(job1)
group.append(job2)
...
cancel(group)
```

Nothing particular about Twisted here - this is just creating a collection and then operating on it.  You don't need the reactor to help or anything.  What you do need is a way to cancel an individual operation.  The latest release of Twisted adds `Deferred.cancel` (so, contrary to the older post linked to in pyfunc's answer, Deferreds do have a notion of being cancelled now).  However, for this to actually do anything, each API which creates Deferreds - for example, `getPage` - has to be updated to perform the relevant cancellation operation.  As of Twisted 10.1, `getPage` has not been updated.

So you can either implement cancellation for `getPage` (and contribute it to Twisted, please!) or you can forget about actually cancelling the HTTP request and instead just ignore the result when it arrives.

Answer (score 0):

I am not providing the solution but pointing out to a following relevant discussion on twisted mailing list.

- http://www.mail-archive.com/twisted-python@twistedmatrix.com/msg01193.html